# UWP MapControl sample traffic app

Tags: uwp-xaml

Modify the traffic app from microsoft (https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-appsample-trafficapp)

1) Added a HomePage and load on initialise in app.xaml.cs.  Then add a button which navigate to MainPage
2) Also add a button on the MainPage which navigate back to the HomePage.

Does anyone know how to fix the following?
1) After navigate back and forth few times between two pages, the mapcontrol gets into a state where it only show the current location and a single pin instead of all six pins.

2) Is there anyway to detect if the mapcontrol is ready for user interaction.  I would like to show a progress ring until the mapcontrol has been drawn properly and ready to zoom. As at the moment, it shows a black screen then loads up the mapcontrol.

3) Lastly, on the initial load, the pins shows up on the top right corner on the mapcontrol before the mapcontrol display.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Without a sample I doubt that anyone can help you. Please share with us a sample for your question.

Comment: This is many questions which sound like you're asking us to code a solution to a school problem or something. SO is solving small, specific programming issues. Get started and some back with specific issues you have. :)

Comment: Here are the steps:  from the github project - [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-appsample-trafficapp). Modify project as add a HomePage view, in the xaml <Button Content="Open traffic app" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" /> and in the code behind with     private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { Frame.Navigate(typeof (MainPage)); }.  Then change the app.xaml.cs from MainPage to HomePage.  Add a similar button to the MainPage and navigate to HomePage.

Comment: @samiles I have asked three questions all related to the same control/project.  This way it would be better than submitting three separate stackoverflow questions!

Comment: @Jennifer I understand, but that isn't how SO works!! We would much prefer multiple specific questions about programming problems than one broad "How do I implement..." question. [Here's more info.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **We need actual code you have tried to be able to answer - otherwise we are just coding the solution for you. We need code and to know what the problem you have is :)**